# How to correct CSS formatting problem in Visual Studio

Tags: css, visual-studio-2008

I've developed a webpage in visual studio, but whenever I open the page in "view in browser" the formatting is skewed (I used line-height attribute, but it didn't work. Please see sample). Yet whenever I upload the site to a real server, the formatting is correct again. Does that mean I need to install IIS to view the site properly? Thanks!

Sample

http://i1230.photobucket.com/albums/ee495/hkingdev/page.jpg

Comment: What do you mean by "the formatting is skewed"?  Can you show us?

Comment: attached a sample here. thanks

Comment: What renderer does the "view in browser" use? Internet Explorer? What browser does the page render correctly in?

Comment: View in browser uses internet explorer. The same Internet Explorer renders correctly if the page is uploaded to a server.

Comment: Let's see some source... show us your HTML and CSS.  Compare the two from when you preview and when you upload as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, this is not directly related to Visual Studio. It may just mean there is a problem with your layout.

You should be testing all your pages in all of the major browsers. If they all work, then I wouldn't worry about it. But I suspect some browsers may have problems formatting your page.

And if you are using a different browser to preview your site than you are using to view it on the server, then that's your answer. You need to test with all major browsers.